# Calculation in Tableau gives wrong result

Tags: tableau-api

I have a calculation to make

For each club and Operator I want to create Revenues with the following formula

```
Revenue = successfulbillinghits * pricePerBilling * Rate * Multiple Factor
```

**Components are:**

- Successfulbillinghits = Number of billings for a customer
- PricePerBilling = Price of per billing (Keep changing)
- Currency Exchange Rate = Currency Rate from local currency to dollar (Keep changing)
- Multiple Factor = Constant for each club and operator

**I have tried:**

```
Revenue = SUM([successfulbillinghits])*ATTR([pricePerBilling])*AVG([Rate])*ATTR([Multiple Factor])
```

**Result:**
Successfulbillinghits is fine (Gives sensible result)
Multiple factor is fine (Gives sensible result)

**Problem** is with the following where it gives `*`
PricePerBilling
Currency Exchange Rate

**What I want:**
I want each PricePerBilling and exchange rate of the row! e.g. if there are 10 rows and there are 3 different price billings and 10 different exchange rates, i want tableau to check the 10 individual rows and get the corresponding exchange rate and the billing rate.

Using tableau desktop

Here is the sample (Column names are shortened)

```
Op  Cl  billinghits Price/Billing Ex-Rate   MultipleFactor  Revenue 
1   2   5           2             0.27      1               2.7
1   2   6           2.5           0.27      1               4.05
1   2   3           2.5           0.28      1               2.1
1   2   4           2             0.27      1               2.16
                                                     Total: 11.01
```

Result should look like:

```
  Operatpr  Club    Revenue             
    1        2       11.01
```

Comment: Sounds like you need [LOD](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/LOD-expressions)

Comment: I am a newbie. Looked into the articles, tried but gave weird results

Comment: I think it would help if you posted sample data, and examples of what you get with Revenue and what you would like. Screenshots are OK.

Comment: Hold on. I will update

Comment: Something is off in your underlying data source. If you are including `ATTR([pricePerBilling])` and `ATTR([Multiple Factor])`, that means you could have more than one value per row of data. That results in the `*` you are seeing. The `attr()` function documentation says it will return a * if there is more than one value. Can you post an image of your data pane so we can see the dimensions and measures? Are you using a blended data source?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you should calculate `revenue` as a new column, and for each row compute the following formula, without any aggregation.

```
Revenue = [successfulbillinghits] * [pricePerBilling] * [Rate] * [Multiple Factor]
```

And then you can plot `Operatpr`, `Club`, and `SUM(Revenue)`, which will automatically aggregate (group by) `Operatpr` and `Club` and print the sum of the revenue per group.

Comment: I tried this the very first time. It gives * with the changing values

Comment: please update question with screenshot of the `*` that you see

Answer (score 0):

create a calculated field as 
{fixed [Cl],[Op] : SUM(([Billingnights]*[Ex-Rate]*[MultipleFactor]*[Price/Billing]))}. Name it Revenue

and Drag this Op, Cl and Revenue to the view.